# Not able to use 1.3.0.RELEASE of spring-boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am not able to use 1.3.0.RELEASE version of spring-boot in my project. Following is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am getting following error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.elm:elm:[unknown-version]: Failure to find
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.0.RELEASE
>   in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM   pom.xml /elm    line
>   8 Maven pom Loading Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local cached repository seems to be messed up.

Either you can force `maven` to download dependencies with

```
mvn clean install -U
```

or you can clean your cached repository by removing `<USER_HOME>/.m2/repository` directory.